# Congratulations Luboš Motl

Tags: discussion, tags, badges

[Luboš Motl](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/1236/lubos-motl) has become the first ever user on Physics.Stackexchange to get a [Gold Badge for  a particular topic](https://physics.stackexchange.com/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold) . He has earned the Gold Badge for [quantum-mechanics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quantum-mechanics) , [all time top user](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/quantum-mechanics/topusers) in the tag.

Cheers for his great achievement !!

> Luboš Motl,
>
> Thanks for your incomparable contribution to the community.

Comment: Yep, it is great that we have Lumo :-). Without him, many advanced questions would stay unanswered ... I congratulate and thank him for his contributions too :-)

Comment: Common @ϚѓăʑɏβµԂԃϔ, dont be a party pooper ... :-P. The SE stuff and owners want jump down on as for having such a question to honor an exceptional member of our community on meta ;-). Take it easy, you are not the (SE) police, or are you ;-D?

Comment: @Dilaton: Maybe, I'll get a gold tag-specialist badge within a few more years (not too far)... Would you honor me? C'mon, this shows something interesting to everyone. But, it's not an interesting topic to ***discuss*** ;-)

Comment: @ϚѓăʑɏβµԂԃϔ yep, then you should be hohored too :-D, since things of interest and importance to our physics SE community should always be ok per decret. This thread is something nice nobody has to disagree and fight upon, it is just to celebrate so this is good. Cheers :-)

Comment: I don't see any harm in praising Lubos for their accomplishments on the site here, @ϚѓăʑɏβµԂԃϔ. This is a milestone for the *site*...

Comment: @Shog9: Agreed. But, can we create a tag [meta-tag:specific-user] and discuss around about a particular *user*..? For example, we did discuss about Ron Maimon (Err.. his *suspension*) and finally [it got closed](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/2713/11062). I always think that metas are only for discussing about scope of main site, what are the allowables, observables, what do we accept/agree with, etc. Isn't that so? ;-)

Comment: Yeah, probably not a great tag @ϚѓăʑɏβµԂԃϔ. I've replaced it.

Comment: congrats Lubos.

Comment: @Ϛѓăʑɏ βµԂԃϔ  I was thinking, maybe we should have a "Maimongate" tag for when we want to discuss this issue.  It will help future internet historians.

Comment: @twistor59: Yeah... Of course. That tag with a tag-wiki excerpt to the *You-know-who*-related question (Hope someone would understand that) ;-)

Comment: @twistor59 yep, I immediately thought we should create a memorial thread for another now unfortunately gone great contributer, who enlightend us with his brilliant answer and always higlighted the importance of unhinderend open discours and blatant honesty in science, too :-). Hi is still missed by many and it would at least help me to find some peace again and get over the bad circumstances of his departure a bit.

Comment: But here is not the place for this, since this is Lumo's party thread :-).Cheers

Comment: @Dilaton you must have noticed that Ron is still getting quite a number of points every month with his old answers. Also he does look in at the site practically every day.

Comment: Which sourball had to downvote this celebration post, as even Shog9 said it is ok?

Comment: Only physicists would close a question like this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your warm and kind words, colleagues and e-pals. I hope that there will also be contributions in the future and many people will also be made happy and fewer people will be provoked by my (and other) answers!

And congratulations to quantum mechanics for having earned the gold badge – this sometimes underappreciated princess of the 20th century physics deserves it and it's really her achievement, too. ;-)

Comment: well done Lubos, I always learn something from your answers.

Comment: Me too. I always learn and appreciate your answers a lot. It is great to have you here. Thanks, Lubos!

Comment: Congrats on your second gold badge now (for qft) : )

Comment: Dear Lubos, Congrats on your 100k achievement! I've always found your answers interesting. Keep up the good work :)

Comment: 100k... wooohooo!!

Comment: They just offered me "swag" - T-shirts, mugs etc. ;-)